# Apache2 not running PHP, only displaying code as text. Worked before upping to PHP7.3, I have researched and tested

Tags: php, apache2

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache2
PHP 7.3

I have reinstalled Apache2.
A phpinfo.php file containing

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

simply shows the code.

I have tried, following 
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-apache-2-not-executing-php-files/,
adding to my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file the lines

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
​SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

then saved the file then tried to restart Apache2 with

```sh
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

But code is still being displayed rather than phpinfo() being evaluated.

Which PHP is running:

```
$ php -v

PHP 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2019 12:54:24) ( NTS )

Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

with Zend OPcache v7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Which modules are loaded in Apache2:

```
$ apache2ctl -M
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.10. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)

(how do I format this pretty!?)

Installation of

```
$ sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3
[sudo] password for gt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php7.3' for regex 'ibapache2-mod-php7.3'
libapache2-mod-php7.3 is already the newest version (7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Did you check that the LoadModule config in your httpd.conf points to the new PHP?

Comment: can you type php -v into your terminal? also type apache2ctl -M post the results

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct Apache module package installed from Ubuntu: `libapache2-mod-php7.3`, I believe. I know the article mentioned modules but you didn't ;-)

Comment: cOle2, By 'httpd.conf' should I understand 'apache2.conf'?  or, where would 'htpd.conf' hide? 'LoadModule' does not occur in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file. Thanks.

Comment: MHewiston, thanks.  I've entered the commands at the CLI, and edited my Q with the results.

Comment: Greg J Preace, thanks.  I've edited my Q to show that, according to apt, I do have libapache2-mod-php7.3 installed.